# Assigning a value to variable shows read only error

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, variables

**component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  details:{a: boolean,
           b:boolean,
           c:boolean,
           x:number} = {
    a: false,
    b: false,
    c: false,
    x: 0,
  };

  public get value(): number {
    const numbermap = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 } //value of checkboxes;
    return Object.entries(this.details)
      // get only the entries with true value
      .filter(([_key, value]) => value)
      // map the keys having true to an array of numbers
      .map(([key]) => numbermap[key])
      // requred for preventing error from reduce if none selected `[].reduce()`
      .concat(0)
      // sum the numbers with reduce
      .reduce((prev = 0, curr) => prev + curr)
  }

  submit() {
    this.value = this.details.x; //Assigning value to variable
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}
```

What i'm doing is I've created cheeckboxes a,b,c which holds a value 1 2 3 respectively. When true each checkboxes value gets added . But when I'm trying to assign this value to x (in details array) I get an error "x is a readonly property".

Comment: This is a Vue file?, is React?, Typescript for VanillaJS? 
What have u tried, and which errors do you get are valuelable too. Not only the questions itself

Comment: It's angular 10

Answer (score 0):

Your `value` getter method's name is colliding with a `value` property on the instance. You could:

- Choose a different name, eg, use `getValue` instead of a `value` getter, allowing you to use `this.value` as a normal property
- Add a setter for `value` as well, eg:

  ```
  set value(newValue) {
    this._value = newValue;
  }
  ```

  (and define the type for `this._value`)
- Since the only place the value looks to be used is in `submit`, you could remove the assignment to the instance entirely and use a local variable instead, if that's what you're intending:

  ```
    submit() {
    const val = this.details.x;
    console.log(val);
  }
  ```

Comment: I want to push the value to "x" in details object when I do so it says read only error

Comment: Did you mean to do `this.details.x = this.value`? Your current code goes the other way around

Comment: yes I need to push that value to this.x.value so that i can send it to firebase or else it assigns an id to data

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a set for the job of assigning values to `value`.

Example:

```
  public set value(new_value: number) {
    this.details.x = new_value;
  }
```

Comment: What is new_value ?

Comment: The value you want to set for you instance of detalies.x. Than you should use set inside the `submit` function.